# Subshell failing when run through cron

Tags: cron, shell, shell-scripting

I have a file:

```
/etc/bind/dnsCron/dnsCron.sh
```

I run it via cron every 5 minutes:

```
*/5 * * * * sh /etc/bind/dnsCron/dnsCron.sh
```

Inside `dnsCron.sh` I have a line that succeeds when I run it command line .. But it fails in the cron  -- Error log:

```
/etc/bind/dnsCron/dnsCron.sh: 124: /etc/bind/dnsCron/dnsCron.sh: named-checkconf: not found
```

The line(s) in question: **dnsCron.sh**

```
    >/etc/bind/dnsCron/checkconf
    named-checkconf -z > /etc/bind/dnsCron/checkconf
```

Is there anything wrong with running a `subshell` in an `shell script` called by `crontab`?  I have a feeling it doesn't like me calling **named-checkconf** directly.  What's the correct way to get `named-checkconf -z` results into the file `checkconf` when run through `crontab`?

Comment: Fix your path.  The error is telling you it can't find the command, and that's because it's not in the PATH the shell is using.

Comment: Do you know the path to named-checkconf?

Comment: On your server?  No, no clue.

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04 it's located in `usr/sbin/named-checkconf` ---  If you'd quickly write an answer explaining why the shell run as `root` can see the PATH but cron doesn't.  Does cron not use the same PATH even if cron was run as the same user?  Your suggestion fixed it, I just would like clarification as to "why".